# Intellij + lombok + fat jar => Lombok installer

Tags: spring, macos, intellij-idea, lombok, fatjar

I have a spring boot 2 project, using Lombok (1.18.6) under Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2018.3.
Everything works fine within IntelliJ running as an application.
But when I try to build a fat jar as an artifact and launch it in the terminal (OSX) with :
java -jar my project.jar, I get a Lombok Installer window !!! Any idea ?

Comment: did you build it with maven or gradle ?

Comment: How are you building the fatjar? You should be using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Comment: With Maven, and yes, spring-boot-maven-plugin is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lombok is an annotation processor basically, so there is no point to make the dependency on lombok available in runtime. Read, it should not be a part of spring boot application.

Take a look at `BOOT-INF/lib` - if you see lombok, change the build script . For example for maven, make the dependency of scope "provided"

Comment: Re: the 2nd paragraph. I had this exact problem recently. Spring Boot will put Lombok inside **even if** the scope is 'provided'. You need to manually exclude Lombok.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13289

Comment: @Michael, yes you're right. I haven't concentrated on the technical aspect of how exactly the lombok should be excluded. All-in-all like M. Deinum has stated - usually people use spring-boot-maven-plugin. If more details will show up in the question maybe we'll be able to provide a really working solution...

Comment: Ok thanks ! Well, i’ve tried « provided » and effectively, lombok.jar is still here. So i removed it manually from libraires included in artifact configuration. It seemed to work until a clean and rebuild, now Getters and setters aren’t generated anymore. I’m gonna check my compiler options (i’ve been playing with then a lot trying to solve my initial problem. Anyway thanks, solution is on the go !

Comment: @ChristopheArnal Well, you can't remove it completely since it's required. The problem is presumably that you are not specifying a main class directly, and the plugin is choosing the first one that it finds.